# Bash Script to access Safari Preferences File

Tags: bash, safari

I'm on a mac and want to access the Safari Preferences File using a bash script. I want to know the  default folder set by a user for saving downloaded files. I know that the preferences are in the '/Users/username/Library/Safari' folder on mac.

Which file stores the "Save Downloaded files to:"  value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following commands will access the preference API and write the preference you want.

```
defaults write com.apple.safari DownloadsPath = \"~/Downloads\"
defaults write com.apple.safari NSNavLastRootDirectory = \"~/Downloads\"
```

**DownloadsPath** is the default download directory. **NSNavLastRootDirectory** is the folder last accessed in the Save dialog.

The file is *~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist*, by the by. But using the defaults utility is preferable to manually modifying the file.

Comment: Safari 13 seems to have broken `defaults write com.apple.safari DownloadsPath`. Any idea what the new preference is?